# Executing Windows PowerShell commands in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-notebook

Would someone please suggest a way to execute Windows PowerShell commands (i.e., commands more similar to Unix commands than Command-Prompt commands) in a Jupyter notebook? Please note that I am a layperson.

So far, I have added "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts" to my path system variable, which allows me to run "jupyter-notebook" from either Command Prompt or Windows PowerShell. I guess a shell looks in all folders in my path system variable for an application to run named "juypter-notebook". I guessed that running Jupyter Notebook from Windows PowerShell would allow my Jupyter-Notebook Chrome application to understand PowerShell commands, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: [Jaykul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8718/jaykul) wrote a [Jupyter PowerShell Kernel](https://github.com/Jaykul/Jupyter-PowerShell) that may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi BenH. Thanks for the suggestion. It looked good, but it didn't work for me. Probably because the chocolatey package Jupyter-PowerShell 1.0.0 is in moderation. Any other ideas?

I went to the link above. I installed chocolatey using my Adminstrator Command Prompt. I ran "choco install jupyter-powershell". I received the error "jupyter-powershell not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed. Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'". I navigated to "https://chocolatey.org/packages/jupyter-powershell/1.0.0" and discovered that "This version is in moderation".

Comment: I went ahead and installed Jaykul's Jupyter-Powershell 1.0.0 beta 7 release. Thanks, BenH and Jaykul!

Answer (score 3):

You can execute a PowerShell command from a Jupyter Notebook cell on a Windows machine with:

```
!Powershell.exe -Command "<PowerShell command>"
```

For example, if you wanted to print the first 10 lines of the file `filename.txt`, you could write:

```
!Powershell.exe -Command "type filename.txt -Head 10"
```

[Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-run-powershell-commands-from-the-command-prompt)

Comment: I was able to use simply `!powershell "get-item .\*.csv"` so I'm not sure the explicit .exe (in the command line) or the switch -Command is required now.